# Массовый UPDATE. Как произвести замену множества строк

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть две таблицы. insert_bord и warehouse_bord. В таблице insert_bord сотни записей с полями name, color, quan. В таблице warehouse_bord - name, color, quanAll, quanFree, quanOrd с уникальными name и color.

Требуется находить сумму значений quan в insert_bord по name и color, а затем менять значение quanAll в warehouse_bord на полученную сумму по соответствующим значениям name и color.
Как подсчитать сумму я определился `SELECT i.name, i.color, SUM(i.quan) FROM Insert_bord as i GROUP BY name, color`.

Т.е. мне требуется перенести полученную сумму с картинки 3, на таблицу склада на картинке 2 по параметрам названия и цвета [image: склад продукции] warehouse_bord - Сам склад, куда нужно заносить измененные данные из подсчетов, приведенных на картинке 3.

[image: таблица прироста продукции] Insert_bord - Исходная таблица для подсчетов.

[image: сумма прироста]- подсчеты из запроса выше. Столбец warehouse_bord.quanAll нужно менять на SUM(i.quan) из этой таблицы

Comment: Приведите таблицу из которой вы вытаскиваете `SUM(i.quan)`. Или уточните описание таблиц. Я мало, что понял.

Comment: Таблица такого вида https://prnt.sc/xuw9qd В таблицу вносится ежедневный прирост разной продукции

Comment: Добавьте скрин в вопрос и подпишите скрины.

Comment: Добавил, подписал